# Git status reports the branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master', but git push rejected

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I enter `git status` I get the following:

```
On branch master 
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'
```

But then when I enter `git push` I get this:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:FoxRocks/pams_amo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I am hesitant to simply `git pull` from the repo because I don't know what the differences are. I read another post that said I should enter `git fetch origin` followed by `git diff master origin/master` but neither of these commands return anything at all. I added `-v` thinking I would get more information, but it didn't.

Am I misunderstanding what it means by "up-to-date with 'origin/master'"?

Comment: `origin/master` and the `master` tip in the remote repository could point to different commits. When `master` in the remote repository gets updated by others, `origin/master` in you local repository won't get updated until you run `git fetch` or `git pull`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I misunderstanding what it means by "up-to-date with 'origin/master'"?

Probably, yes. `origin/master` tracks `master` on the remote `origin` but it is still just local and does not stay up to date with the remote automatically. So you can be up to date with  `origin/master` but not with `master` on the remote `origin`. When you try to push, the discrepancy is revealed.

To sync them, `git fetch`. Now `git status` might change its tune! Try it and see.

Comment: I was sure I had already entered `git fetch` but when I tried it just now it actually did something and now when I enter `git status` it gives me a clear picture. Thanks!

Comment: Yay! And I hope you have a clearer idea of what origin/master really is.

Comment: It sure did! One thing I wasn't sure of is once I've entered `git fetch` how to do I now see what changes were added in my latest local commit? I had 5 or 6 files that were changed locally, they we added and committed but not pushed, but after I fetched I couldn't see them with `git status`.

Comment: You would diff master to origin/master